# Eslint rule to put a new line inside import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, es6-modules

The rule that I'm looking should show error in this case:

```
import {MY_CONSTANT1, MY_CONSTANT2, MY_CONSTANT3}
```

And considered as fine in this case:

```
import {
   MY_CONSTANT1, 
   MY_CONSTANT2, 
   MY_CONSTANT3
}
```

Is there such eslint rule?

Comment: There is a proposal for this: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9259#issuecomment-525289402

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for such a rule for both import and export declaration.
As a result I've made a [plugin](https://github.com/gmsorrow/eslint-plugin-modules-newline) with autofix.

So plugin transforms the code

```
import { k1, k2 } from 'something'
```

into

```
import {
  k1,
  k2
} from 'something'
```

and code

```
export { name1, name2, nameN }
```

into

```
export {
  name1,
  name2,
  nameN
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort in putting this together - such a lifesaver for standardizing how we format imports!!

Comment: Note that this plugin should be used alongside other rules to get the mentioned behavior: https://github.com/gmsorrow/eslint-plugin-modules-newline/issues/6#issuecomment-660619725.

Comment: This plugin appears to no longer work.

Answer (score 13):

## Edit:

Anton Antonov made a plugin that enforces this rule better than object-curly-newline can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477269/6179417

---

## Old answer

Add the [object-curly-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline) rule to your `.eslintrc.json`, where at least `ImportDeclaration` is set to always (the other settings have no effect for enforcing newlines in import declarations).

Example:

```
"object-curly-newline": ["error", {
   "ObjectExpression": "always",
   "ObjectPattern": { "multiline": true },
   "ImportDeclaration": "always",
   "ExportDeclaration": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 }
}]
```

This pattern will now result in an error:
[image]

While this is valid:
[image]

However, there is a catch - this rule only requires newlines after the opening brace and before the closing brace, so you can still double up on imports as long as they have newlines in between the braces:
[image]

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error: Error: .eslintrc:
        Configuration for rule "object-curly-newline" is invalid:
        Value "[object Object]" no (or more than one) schemas match.

Comment: I think it can be because of old eslint version

Comment: this is working with new eslint version, but still it doesn't solve the problem as you mentioned at the end

Comment: I think the only way is to write your own eslint rule, which definitely isn't trivial.

Answer (score 6):

### Update on Anton Antonov answer for eslint 8

Because Anton Antonovs repository has been archived and gives meta.fixable error with eslint 8. I Recommend to use ruudandriessen [fork of the project](https://github.com/ruudandriessen/eslint-plugin-modules-newline) .

**How to use fork:**

1. Install fork

```
npm install eslint-plugin-modules-newlines --save-dev
```

2. Change all references inside eslint config file of modules-newline -> modules-newlines

**Error:**

```
ESLint: Fixable rules must set the `meta.fixable` property to "code" or "whitespace".
Occurred while linting ... Rule: "modules-newline/import-declaration-newline".
Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details.
```

Comment: Very important to notice that the archived plugin (not compatible with eslint 8.0) is called:
 eslint-plugin-modules-newline 
The new one that is compatible with eslint 8.0 is called (one extra "s" at the end): 
eslint-plugin-modules-newlines

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the solution and unfortunately have only found your question. I have decided to learn a bit about how eslint works and how to write your own plugins and created mine. If you know the parsed the AST node structure it is really easy to work with. Here is the plugin's main file. Autofix is more tricky though so I do not include it as it biased towards my formatting standards.

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'single-import-per-line': {
      create (context) {
        return {
          ImportDeclaration(node) {
            if (node.specifiers.length < 2) {
              return;
            }

            let previousImport = node.specifiers[0];
            for (let i = 1; i < node.specifiers.length; i++) {
              const currentImport = node.specifiers[i];

              // Omit the first condition if you want to put default imports on a new line as well
              if (previousImport.type !== 'ImportDefaultSpecifier'
                && currentImport.loc.start.line === previousImport.loc.end.line
              ) {
                context.report({ node, message: 'Your message' });
                return;
              }

              previousImport = currentImport;
            }
          },
        };
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score -9):

you can try this

```
"semicolon": [true, "always"]
```